# Font awesome issue Rails 7

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, yarnpkg

I just cloned my repo from Github, ran the rails assets:precomplie and the font awesome gem was installed with the

```
*= require font-awesome
```

included in the application.css

and

```
@import "font-awesome";
```

in the scss file

but the icon does not show (while it was show in another PC that I worked on the repo)

Try link etc. but does not work for me.